# Flyway clean failing to clean due to drop constraint

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, flyway

I am trying to `clean` my MSSQL database. I have this working on some of my databases, but on one of them, I am getting the following error.

```
Unable to clean schema [dbo]
----------------------------
SQL State  : S0001
Error Code : 3717
Message    : Cannot drop a default constraint by DROP DEFAULT statement. Use ALTER TABLE to drop a constraint default.

        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.Schema.clean(Schema.java:151)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean$3.call(DbClean.java:172)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean$3.call(DbClean.java:169)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:74)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean.cleanSchema(DbClean.java:169)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbClean.clean(DbClean.java:113)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doClean(Flyway.java:1488)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$300(Flyway.java:85)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$3.execute(Flyway.java:1506)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$3.execute(Flyway.java:1499)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1711)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.clean(Flyway.java:1499)
        at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.executeOperation(Main.java:157)
        at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:108)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot drop a default constraint by DROP DEFAULT statement. Use ALTER TABLE to drop a con
straint default.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:254)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1608)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:578)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:508)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2869)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:243)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:218)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:493)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:215)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.sqlserver.SQLServerSchema.doClean(SQLServerSchema.java:294)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.Schema.clean(Schema.java:149)
        ... 13 more
```

Many of my tables have default constraints for certain columns. But I can't see how I can change how flyway drops those constraints. I can't find any information on how to workaround this issue. If you have any insight, please help. Thanks!

Comment: This error implies that the server is running SQL Server 2019 in some form. In SQL Server 2017, the Books on Line advised that DROP DEFAULT would be removed from the "next version" of SQL Server. If this is the case, then it appears that `flyway` is not compatible with SQL 2019.

Comment: Hi @LaughingVergil. I am actually running SQL Server 14.0.2002.14 (aka 2017).

Answer (score 0):

Please file an issue in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues) with exact steps how to reproduce including the smallest possible SQL file that triggers this.